# R function - Assigning empty value to create a score

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

```
score<-function(score_A,score_B){
  score_A<-()
  score_B<-()
  if (score_A == score_B){
    print("TIE GAME")
  }
  else if(score_A<score_B){
    print("Team B wins")
  }
  else if(score_A>score_B){
    print("Team A wins")
  }
  else if(score_A & score_B >=5){
    print("No winner")
  }
  }
```

I need my function to produce a score for either team a or b and to output if team A or B wins or if it is a tie.

my current error is that 1, i dont have a null variable for score A and B along with when i put in values it only says team A wins.

Comment: How are you calling this function? What are you passing in? Since `score_A` and `score_B` are your function parameter names, you don't want to run `score_A<-(); score_B<-()` because that will just empty them out (and it's not even valid syntax, maybe you meant `score_A <- c()`). If you want to return values, there's no need to `print()` the value, you can `return()` the value from your function. But it kind of depends on how you are calling the function to know for sure if that will work.

Comment: score <- function (score_A,score_B) {
   if (score_A == score_B){
    print("TIE GAME")
  }else if(score_A<score_B){
    print("Team B wins")
  } else if(score_A>score_B){
    print("Team A wins")
  } else if(score_A & score_B >=5){
    print("No winner")
  }
}
#Call the function
score( score_A = runif(1, 0, 5), #create a random value for score_A and score_B
       score_B = runif(1, 0, 5))

Comment: "produce a score" likely means that your function should _return_ something. The `print` statement is operating as a side-effect, meaning that your function is returning `NULL` (invisibly). To follow "functional programming", having a `print` (or `cat` or `message`) statement is often the _exception_, meaning that the function should be returning something. The benefit of side-effect (perhaps not returning something) is good for functions like `write.csv`, but many other times it's best to consider that you should capture the return value, e.g., `ret <- score(17, 12); ret # [1] "A wins"`.